# How to add labels etc. with EIA shapefiles in R?

Tags: shapefile, r

I'm trying to create a map of US shale basins and I'm very new to creating maps. I have downloaded the shapefiles from the US Energy Information Administration (EIA). I have also, been able to created a basic map with the bases plotted (please see code below). I would like to add labels etc. to this map. I believe these would be in the other files downloaded outside the shapefile.

```
library(maps)
map("state")
shapLocation<- "C:/shapfile/shalegasbasin/"
pcontorta <- readShapePoly(paste(shapLocation,"US_ShaleBasins_EIA_May2011.shp",sep=""))
plot(pcontorta, add=TRUE,  col=adjustcolor("black", alpha.f = 0.6),  border=FALSE)
```

Shapefile from: http://www.eia.gov/maps/layer_info-m.cfm

Description of a shapefile: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at ?text. You can place the labels using the polygon coordinates which will return approximate polygon centroids.

```
library(sp)
Sr1 = Polygon(cbind(c(2,4,4,1,2),c(2,3,5,4,2)))
Sr2 = Polygon(cbind(c(5,4,2,5),c(2,3,2,2)))
Sr3 = Polygon(cbind(c(4,4,5,10,4),c(5,3,2,5,5)))
Srs1 = Polygons(list(Sr1), "1")
Srs2 = Polygons(list(Sr2), "2")
Srs3 = Polygons(list(Sr3), "3")
SpP = SpatialPolygons(list(Srs1,Srs2,Srs3), 1:3)
SpP = SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(SpP, data.frame(ID=1:3))

# Plot polygons and place text based on polygon centroids
plot(SpP)
text(coordinates(SpP)[,1], coordinates(SpP)[,2], paste("p",SpP$ID,sep="-"))
```